# Spring Data Repositiories - add specific parameters to every query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a few repositories that extend `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository`. I have added some methods for searching entities by different parameters, however, in any search, I only want to search for entities that have the `active` field set to `true` (have opted for marking as `active=false` in place of deleting). For example, two sample repositories would look like this:

```
interface XxRepository extends MongoRepository<Xx, String> {

    Optional<Xx> findOneByNameIgnoreCaseAndActiveTrue(String name)

    Page<Xx> findByActiveTrue(Pageable pageable)

    Xx findOneByIdAndActiveTrue(String id)

}

interface YyRepository extends MongoRepository<Yy, String> {

    Optional<Yy> findOneByEmailAndActiveTrue(String email)
}
```

Is there any way that would allow me not to add `byActiveTrue`\ `andActiveTrue` to each and every method and set it up somewhere in one place for all the queries?

Answer (score 4):

Please try this. No need to provide implementation. Change 'active' and 'email' to your db column name.

```
interface YyRepository extends MongoRepository<Yy, String> {
    @Query(value = "{ 'active' : { '$eq': true }, 'email' : ?0 }")
    Optional<Yy> findOneByEmailAndActiveTrue(@Param("email") String email)
}
```

Comment: I already have such naming and the methods in my repo work. I'm just looking for a way to avoid repetitions in the method names.

Comment: You can have whatever method you want. In this way the active true is passed from the query params not the method name.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an template query into the MongoRepository using Criteria. 
Example

```
class abstract MongoRepository<W, X> {

    protected Class<W> typeOfEntity;
    private Class<X> typeOfId;

    public MongoRepository() {
        typeOfEntity = (Class<W>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        typeOfId = (Class<X>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public W get(X id) throws Exception {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<W> q = cb.createQuery(typeOfEntity);
        Root<W> r = q.from(typeOfEntity);

        String idName = CommonEntity.findIdFieldName(typeOfEntity);
        Predicate andClose = cb.and(cb.equal(r.get("active"), true));

        q.where(cb.equal(r.get(idName), id), andClose);

        return em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

After that, you stay confident into the object running way ans stereotyping to run the good type of request.

The `findIdFieldName`is an method using the @Id to get the id field name.

```
public abstract class CommonEntity implements Serializable {

    public static String findIdFieldName(Class cls) {
        for (Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
            String name = field.getName();
            Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
                if (annotations[i].annotationType().equals(Id.class)) {
                    return name;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I like the succinct and readable style of the custom queries in Spring data repositories, so I'm wondering if there is a way to continue using that declarative way of query-building, however without repeating that specific parameter every single time.Not sure if there is any way of implementing it like that, though.

Comment: You can use the inheritance way of coding I purposed you and just field the `W get(X id)` by : `Query q = em.createQuery("Select * From table Where id = :idValue And active = true"); q.setParameters("idValue", id); return em.getSingleResult();`

Comment: After that in each repository object inheriting of `MongoRepository<W, X>` you `@Override` get method by `@Override W get (X id) { super.get(id); }`